# How to close a RadWindow from a RadButton

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik, window, radwindow

The close button on the RadWindow works fine!!!

But I'd like to add a custom RadButton with "Close" that does the same thing....close the RadWindow in .NET (VB or C#)

Is this possible?

Thanks all.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the technology you are talking is ASP.NET.

With that assumption i want to point you to this demo we have on our RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax control suite. This demo showcases the scenario you are looking out for. The rad window contains a button inside the window, which when clicked will close the rad window. here is the link to the demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/clientsideevents/defaultcs.aspx?product=window

Same scenario in ASP.NET MVC is having the following demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window/clientsideapi

Hope this answers your quesiton. Do let me know if this solved your problem

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)